# How to send longpressed KeyEvent with Java code?

Tags: android, keyevent, keycode, dispatch, key-events

How to send longpressed KeyEvent with Java code ? I have seen some examples where they use shell commands to achieve that goal, but I want to know is there a way to do it only by Java.

The idea is to send longpressed KeyEvent from the remote controller application to Android Box.